# Summatory with Python and how associate sets with vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, docplex

I have a set of nodes:

```
nodes = ["uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis"]
```

and its set of all possible pairs

```
pairs = [(i,j) for i in nodes for j in nodes if i!=j]
```

Also, I have a vector of this set of pairs

```
d = [9, 26, 19, 13, 12, 11, 14, 26, 7, 18, 30, 19, 30, 24, 8, 21, 9,
         11, 22, 16, 14, 14, 8, 9, 20, 26, 1, 22, 24, 13]
```

Each element of this vector it is associated with each element of the set of pairs. First pair with 9, second pair with 26, and so on.

There is the binary variable

```
Z = mdl.binary_var_dict(pairs, name = "Z")
```

associated with the set of pairs

The problem is that I am trying to write the expression

```
sum((d[p]*Z[p]) for p in pairs)
```

but I cannot do that because the vector d is not associated with the set of pairs.

How do I must write?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about completely understanding your explanation but it seems you just need to iterate vector d at the same time isn't it?

```
prod = [d[i]*Z[p]) for i, p in enumerate(pairs)]
sum_ = sum(prod)
```